# How to detect when you can't go back any further in the navigation stack in React-router-dom useNavigate()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I implemented a "back" button which sets `navigate(-1)`, where `navigate` is declared with `const navigate = useNavigate()`. I am using `react-router-dom: v6.21.0` with `reactstrap`.

I can successfully go back but I want to detect if I can no longer go back (empty navigation stack) and disable this button. How would I do that check?

I tried looking into `useLocation()` and the `pathname` parameter with the homepage (`pathname: '/'`), but it doesn't work because a user may go between pages and the homepage at some point and the back button should allow them to go all the way back. Instead, by using the `pathname`, it shortcuts the back button preventing a user from going back when there is supposedly more pages left on the navigation stack.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just FYI it is generally frowned upon or considered poor UX to "trap" users on your page by blocking/preventing back navigations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DrewReese. 

I was planning on doing it to disable my custom back button when the user cannot go back any further. They can still use the browser button to go back but when the UI is embedded in a different screen, if a user goes back far enough, they won't be able to go back anymore and disabling the back button will inform users of that rather than nothing happening. That was my thinking at least.

Should we not disable the back button when the user can't go back any further? Thanks again.

Comment: I think it depends on the UI you are presenting your users. If the button/icon always looks like a "back button" then I think it's reasonable that continued clicking will just keep going back in the browser history, up to and including back navigation back out of the app. If you detected that React-Router doesn't have any more "in-app" history and you swapped to a "go home" button/icon, then I don't think users would be confused by that. Does this make sense?

Comment: There might be a UX issue with that though with "click-happy" users who think they are navigating back and then all of a sudden get redirected to your app's home page or whatever and are left wondering what happened.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! It didn't occur to me to change the button but I also see the potential problems. I'll try to figure something out and see which makes more sense with users. I think that redirecting to the homepage could work since they would just stay on the same page at the point where they can't go back any further.